# Error in inserting into sqlite database when running in Windows XP

Tags: c#, sqlite

This is my code:

```
public DatabaseConnection(String inputFile)
{
    dbConnection = String.Format("Version=3,uri=file:{0}", inputFile);
}

public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    SqliteConnection cnn = new SqliteConnection(dbConnection);
    cnn.Open();
    IDbCommand mycommand = cnn.CreateCommand();
    mycommand.CommandText = sql;

    int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
    return rowsUpdated;
}

public bool AddNewCustomer(CustomerInfo ci)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO CustomerInfo( CustomerName, Residence, PhoneNumber, DateAdded, Remarks, UserID, Token, Fingerprint) values ('00001 ','','','14/03/19 14:53:35','','\"00001 <abc@gfd.gf>\"','','C90444661602D643F86E25975C93ABA81E9A71F5');");
        int result = dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
        if (result != -1)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Fail.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteSyntaxException syntaxEx)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error." + "\n" + syntaxEx.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

No problem when I run my code in windows 7, but exception appear when run in windows xp.

Here exception:
[image]

I thought problem here is permission, but not. With the sql statement in code , I execute successful with command line.

[image]

Help me! Thank!

Comment: What is the actual path of the database file?

Comment: @CL The path of the database file is in same directory with .exe file.

Comment: And what is the actual path of the database file?

Comment: Omit. The select, update and delete statements is execute successful. Only insert statements have error.

Comment: @CL C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\CustomerManage\CustomerManage\bin\Debug\CustomerManage.s3db

Comment: And your user account is "Administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Account is "Administrator".

Comment: More, the database file is regenerated in a different directory - Desktop.

Comment: What do you mean with "regenerated in a different directory"? Do you have two files?

Comment: When running program, auto generate a new database file, no data, 0 byte, in a different dirrectory.

Comment: What is the exact value of the `inputFile` variable?

Comment: Thank @CL. I fixed this error. The cause of this issue is auto changing the current directory in Windows XP, when I choose the path in OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog or FolderBrowseDialog.

Comment: Solution for this issue: Add the follow line of code after choose a path in OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog or FolderBrowseDialog: `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(working_path);`